# Red and White Flower or purely Pink? Phenotype of a Flower Species with a Co-dominant Trait

Tags: genetics, allele

As I understand it, *co-dominance* is when both genes in an allelomorphic pair produce both their effects **equally** on the organism in question whilst *incomplete dominance* applies to an instance where a mix of the effects of two alleles are present — i.e. where one allele is not completely masked by the other.

However, I had this notion challenged by the following paragraph I obtained from a reputable online source:

> Carnation plants show co-dominance for the anthocyanin gene. There are two alleles:
>
> $F^A$ – allele for anthocyanin pigment (red flowers)
>
> $F^N$ – allele for no anthocyanin pigment (white flowers)
>
> ---
>
> **[...] a carnation plant heterozygous for this gene would yield pink flowers [...]**

Shouldn't the phenotype of the flower be **red and white** as opposed to being **pink**, as the alleles have been said to exhibit co-dominance? Anything I am probably missing out on?

---

### EDIT

I have bountied this question because I think I have a major hole with my understanding on this topic somewhere; to give you some perspective, I am a High-School Sophomore currently on an introductory course in Mendelian Genetics/Inheritance.
I read through @swbarnes2's answer where they say:

> In the case of flowers, *if you have two different alleles for the same pigment gene, you **will** see a blending*, because all the pigment-making cells will produce from both alleles.

In such a case (if this always happens), where do the ideas of codominance and incomplete dominance come in? According to my textbook, the following terms are defined as:

> If both genes of an allelomorphic pair produce their effects in an individual (i.e neither allele is dominant to the other) the alleles are said to be co-dominant.

[image: codominance]

> Incomplete dominance applies to a case where the effect of the recessive allele is not completely masked by the dominant allele (in this case, I assume, a blending would occur)

[image]

(I do get that this may not apply to carnation plants, but would it be safe to follow the phenotypes predicted by my textbook definitions for all other cases?)

Hope someone could clear my doubt; I am extremely confused to read (in the comments section) why co-dominance would not mean both colors/phenotypes are shown simultaneously — like being red and white (as opposed to them mixing into pink).

Comment: "*from a reputable online source*" -- I appreciate your direct quoting of the source, but could you also provide a link to it?

Comment: What color does red and white make?

Comment: Mix them together & I'd expect pink. But that's purely for incomplete dominance, isn't it? Should be white & red (individually) when it's co-dominant

Comment: @BryanKrause I understand Shane's concern. Incomplete dominance is typically taught as as a blending of phenotypes (red + white = pink), whereas co-dominance is taught as the simultaneous expression of two phenotypes (red and white banding). This may be outside the scope of the question, but is seems like the genetics of anthocyanin pigmentation in carnations are [in reality more complicated](https://www.wildflower.org/expert/show.php?id=6432) than presented in Shane's question.

Comment: @acvill I mean really, all the notions about dominance are outdated in modern molecular biology; they're good tools for understanding Mendelian genetics where one has access only to lineage information and not any molecular biology, but once you know more they are rarely actually meaningful distinctions. I think that's what's happening here; there's a blending between the understanding of the phenotypes as colors, and the understanding of the phenotypes as enzymatic reactions. I guess that's probably what an answer should explain, I do think I have a better idea now of where OP is coming from.

Comment: @BryanKrause I agree, though someone new to genetics doesn't have that insight, and your first comment came across as dismissive. Maybe [this question concerning the molecular basis of incomplete dominance](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/88542/52196) is relevant.

Comment: @acvill Thank you for the link; I took a look at it, but there wasn't much in there I could really understand, being a high school student!

Comment: Re: "why co-dominance would not mean both colors/phenotypes are shown simultaneously" Not mentioned here is the *scope* of the phenotype. Is it one flower? One cell in a flower? The whole plant? As Bryan mentioned, often "the notions about dominance are outdated in modern molecular biology". The red and white patches in your flower photo seem to me to be an example of "variegation" rather than co-dominance.

Comment: As I think other commenters have implied, I think that you are applying the definitions from the textbook more strictly than the writers of the textbook. In practice the dividing line between these things is not always so clear. A cleaner example of codominance might be one allele which affects color (red) and the other allele affecting something else, like pattern of expression- e.g. pigment only at the tips. In this case you can enumerate the combinations (all red, red tips, all white). Mechanistically I think this situation is rarer (?) but it's clearer for the definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, that nomenclature is kind of old-fashioned; it predates our understanding of what's going on at a molecular level.  Don't get hung up on the language.  Lots and lots of genes and alleles just don't fit into the paradigm of dominant and recessive, and trying to force them to fit doesn't really work.

In the case of flowers, if you have two different alleles for the same pigment gene, you will see a blending, because all the pigment-making cells will produce from both alleles.  There really is no such thing as "white" pigment; either it's causing a color outside the visual spectrum, or it's a broken version of a gene in the pathway that should be making a color-absorbing molecule.  We would usually more properly refer to this as "haploinsufficiency".

If you had blue and red alleles, it would likely make a purple flower, not one that was blue in some patches, red in others.

For something like blood type, AB blood cells make both A and B molecules on their surface (O is broken), but AB is just as good as A in terms of causing an immune reaction; there is no alteration in phenotype due to the lower dose of each allele.

Answer (score 1):

This is not co-dominance, it is the result of either a transposon or a viral infection, similar to the tulip-breaking virus.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip_breaking_virus

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. We're looking for long answers that provide explanation, context, and include references to reliable sources. Don't just give a short answer with a link; instead, explain why your answer is right with appropriate citations. Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then delete or [edit] your post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Friend..you got the meaning of co dominance and incomplete dominance correct... but let me make co dominance easy... its just like mixing colors on a color plate...think it just like that.... otherwise in real sense both colors are indivisually expressed but being expressed in equal amount and with uniformity they appear as pink... other example could be ABO Blood group in humans....as for refrence https://www.genome.gov/genetics-glossary/Codominance *hope it helps..*

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This looks like it could become a good answer with work, but answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if they include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and thus inappropriate for this site. A good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609). In addition, it is best to leave poor questions unanswered. ——— Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [answer] and [ask] effectively on this site.